# Unity C# Input.GetMouseDown(1) only happening once in update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i've been working on some code for a game in Unity and i am using the Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) function. However, it only works the first time i press the left click in the game and no other times after that. The code for the player controller where it's used is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public Transform enemy;
public Transform shot;
public GameObject shotObj;
public Text scoreT;
public Text timeT;
public Text roundT;
public float health;
public float damageTaken;
public Vector3 lookPoint;
public float shotSpeed;

private Camera mainCamera;
private int round = 1;
private int tempRound = 0;  
private float time = 300;
private bool win = false;   
private bool allowShoot;
private EnemyController enemyScript;
private ShotController shotScript;
private bool tempImune = false;
private int targetTime;
private int score = 0;
private int defeatedEnemy = 0;
private GameObject enemyObj;

//coroutine
IEnumerator Pause(float timE)
{
    allowShoot = false;
    //time since the object was created
    float start = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    //sets the game to slow down to 0 movement
    Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
    //loops until start up time is less than start time + pause time
    while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < start + timE)
    {
        //returns null from the subroutine and restarts the subroutine at this point after null (0) time has passed
        yield return null;
    }
    //sets the gamne to be running at normal speed
    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    allowShoot = true;
    if (timE == 5.0f)
    {
        roundT.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

void Start () {
    //center mouse
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    //set camera to be the camera in the scene (should only ever be one camera in the scene)
    mainCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    //set default text values
    scoreT.text = "Score: 000000";
    timeT.text = "Time Left: 600";
    roundT.text = "Round: " + round;
    //pause game before first round begins
    StartCoroutine(Pause(5.0f));
}

void Update () {

    //looka at mouse script
    Ray cameraRay = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Plane ground = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
    float rayLength;

    if (ground.Raycast(cameraRay, out rayLength))
    {
        lookPoint = cameraRay.GetPoint(rayLength);
        transform.LookAt(new Vector3(lookPoint.x, transform.position.y, lookPoint.z));
    }

    //enemy spawner check and win criteria check
    if (defeatedEnemy != 45)
    {
        if (round != tempRound)
        {
            spawnEnemy();
            roundT.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            if (round == 5)
            {
                roundT.text = "Round: " + round + "(Final Round)";
            }
            else
            {
                roundT.text = "Round: " + round;
            }
            StartCoroutine(Pause(5.0f));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        win = true;
    }

    //timer and win check
    if (health == 0f)
    {
        win = true;
    }
    if (!win)
    {
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        timeT.text = "Time Left: " + time;
    }
    else
    {
        if (health == 0f)
        {
            roundT.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            int finalScore = Mathf.RoundToInt(score * ((time / 2) / 10));
            roundT.text = "To Bad, You Loose! Score = " + finalScore;
            Debug.Log(finalScore);
            StartCoroutine(Pause(99999f));
        }
        else
        {
            roundT.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            int finalScore = Mathf.RoundToInt(score * ((time / 2) / 10));
            roundT.text = "Congratulations! Score = " + finalScore;
            Debug.Log(finalScore);
        } 
    }

    //movement controlls
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    //shoot controll
    if (allowShoot)
    {
        Debug.Log("shot allowed");
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //var spawnShot = Instantiate(shot, this.transform.position + new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f), this.transform.rotation);
            //shotScript = shotObj.GetComponent<ShotController>();



            //if (shotScript.enemy)
            //{
            //    Debug.Log("enemy found");
            //    enemyScript = shotScript.enemy.GetComponent<EnemyController>();
            //    if(enemyScript.health <= 0.0f)
            //    {
            //        score += 20;
            //        defeatedEnemy += 1;
            //        scoreT.text = "Score: " + score;
            //        Debug.Log("enemy killed : " + defeatedEnemy);
            //    }
            //}
            Debug.Log("mouseDown");
            int layermask = 1 << 8;
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layermask))
            {
                enemyObj = hit.transform.gameObject;
                enemyScript = enemyObj.GetComponent<EnemyController>();
                Debug.Log("hit");
                //hit.transform.SendMessage("HitByRay");
                if (enemyScript.health == 0f)
                {
                    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                    score += 20;
                    defeatedEnemy += 1;
                    scoreT.text = "Score: " + score;
                    Debug.Log("enemy killed : " + defeatedEnemy);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //enemy existance check
    if (GameObject.Find("Enemy(Clone)") == null)
    {
        round = round + 1;
    }

    if (tempImune)
    {
        if (Mathf.RoundToInt(time) == targetTime)
        {
            tempImune = false;
        }
    }
}

void spawnEnemy()
{
    tempRound = round;
    for (int i = 1; i <= round * 3; i++)
    {
        var spawnEnemy = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Random.Range(-14.5f, 14.5f), 0.25f, Random.Range(-6f, 6f)), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        if (!tempImune)
        {
            health = health - damageTaken;
            Debug.Log(health);
            tempImune = true;
            targetTime = Mathf.RoundToInt(time) - 1;
        }            
    }
}
```

}

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as it's for a school project. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to read 200 lines of code.

Comment: That's how [getKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) works. Works once when you click it. [getKeyUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html) works when you release the key. [getKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) works when you click it, continuously

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user has released the mouse button and pressed it again. button values are 0 for the primary button (often the left button), 1 for secondary button, and 2 for the middle button

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class ClassName : MonoBehaviour 
    {
    void Update()
    {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        Debug.Log("Pressed primary button.");

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        Debug.Log("Pressed secondary button.");

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        Debug.Log("Pressed middle click.");
    }
    }
```

Comment: It is being called within the update function, the issue is that when the game loads, i click and release once and it works fine, however after that it wont work again. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried to do the same functionality on new project for testing purpose ? sometimes librarry get missing within development project , so try that

Comment: but i dont see any update functions on your keybored , what are you firing on getmountbuttondown ?

Comment: i made a test project to test it and this time it didn't register the mouse click at all, any advice?

Comment: on mouse click, it's causing a raycast that's checking for any collisions

Answer (score 0):

If you click your mouse button it will only work for a frame, right?

Where you used `(Input.Getmousebuttondown(0))` try to use
`(Input.Getmousebutton(0))`:

```
if (allowShoot)
{
    Debug.Log("shot allowed");
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //var spawnShot = Instantiate(shot, this.transform.position + new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f), this.transform.rotation);
        //shotScript = shotObj.GetComponent<ShotController>();



        //if (shotScript.enemy)
        //{
        //    Debug.Log("enemy found");
        //    enemyScript = shotScript.enemy.GetComponent<EnemyController>();
        //    if(enemyScript.health <= 0.0f)
        //    {
        //        score += 20;
        //        defeatedEnemy += 1;
        //        scoreT.text = "Score: " + score;
        //        Debug.Log("enemy killed : " + defeatedEnemy);
        //    }
        //}
        Debug.Log("mouseDown");
        int layermask = 1 << 8;
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layermask))
        {
            enemyObj = hit.transform.gameObject;
            enemyScript = enemyObj.GetComponent<EnemyController>();
            Debug.Log("hit");
            //hit.transform.SendMessage("HitByRay");
            if (enemyScript.health == 0f)
            {
                Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                score += 20;
                defeatedEnemy += 1;
                scoreT.text = "Score: " + score;
                Debug.Log("enemy killed : " + defeatedEnemy);
            }
        }
    }
}

//enemy existance check
if (GameObject.Find("Enemy(Clone)") == null)
{
    round = round + 1;
}

if (tempImune)
{
    if (Mathf.RoundToInt(time) == targetTime)
    {
        tempImune = false;
    }
}
```

}

I had this problem yesterday and I think this is the solution. Keep in mind I have been coding for 2 weeks.